# Passing string 'by value' change in local value reflect in original value

Tags: c++, string, pass-by-value

Why is the change of my local variable's value getting reflected into original variable?  I am passing it *by value* in C++.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void test(std::string a)
{
    char *buff  =  (char *)a.c_str();

    buff[2] = 'x';
    std::cout << "In function: "  << a;

}
int main()
{
    std::string s = "Hello World";
    std::cout  << "Before : "<< s << "\n" ;
    test(s);
    std::cout << "\n" << "After : " << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### Output:

```
Before : Hello World
In function: Hexlo World
After : Hexlo World
```

Comment: You have a bug in your program, invoking undefined behaviour. Something unexpected happened. That shouldn't be surprising. The bug is this: `buff[2] = 'x';`.

Comment: I think the bug is already at `char *buff  =  (char *)a.c_str();`

Comment: @Ped7g That allows the bug to compile, but in itself doesn't cause UB. But yes, I would consider that a bug too.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour, as mentioned.  I get output that differs from yours, and somebody else may get a program crash, or [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html), or anything.

Comment: @Ped7g Shouldn't the compiler complain for that line?

Comment: @Bob__ he's overriding it by C-like cast (otherwise it wouldn't compile). It's not like in C++ you can't shoot in your foot, if you want to. Actually the language will gladly support you with all kinds of bazookas and weapons of mass destruction, most of the time only one warning away.

Answer (score 5):

As soon as you wrote

```
buff[2] = 'x';
```

and compiled your code all bets were off.  Per [string.accessors]

> ```
> const charT* c_str() const noexcept;
> ```
>
> 1. `Returns:` A pointer `p` such that `p + i == &operator[](i)` for each `i` in `[0,size()]`.
> 2. `Complexity:` constant time.
> 3. `Requires:` **The program shall not alter any of the values stored in the character array.**

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

Since you are not allowed to modify the characters that the pointer points to but you do, you have undefined behavior.  The compiler at this point is allowed to do pretty much whatever it wants.  Trying to figure out why it did what it did is meaningless as any other compiler might not do this.

The moral of the story is do not cast `const` away unless you are really sure that you know what you are doing and if you do you need to, then document the code to show you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your `std::string` implementation uses reference counting and makes a deep copy only if you modify the string via its `operator[]` (or some other method). Casting the `const char*` return value of `c_str()` to `char*` will lead to undefined behavior.

I believe since C++11 `std::string` must not do reference counting anymore, so switching to C++11 might be enough to make your code work (**Edit:** I did not actually check that before, and it seems my assumption was wrong).

To be on the safe side, consider looking for a string implementation that guarantees deep copying (or implement one yourself).

Comment: Even in C++ 14 I am getting the same output.

Comment: Pardon me, but are you really recommending to switch implementation, while the OP is casting `const` pointer to writable one, and wondering it is causing havoc? How about considering to simply not cast `const` to non-const pointer? If you want that string in writable array, just do strcpy(buffer, str.c_str()) with all those error-prone situations like buffer overflow if you do it wrong way... but I mostly wonder what's wrong about `str[2] = 'x';`? @Distraction

Comment: If I am not able to do some processing on local variable passing it 'by value', then what will be the use of 'pass by value' concept? For this case it become like 'pass by reference'.

Comment: gcc used non-C++11-compliant `std::string` for a while (i think they changed in gcc 6.0)

Comment: @Distraction you seem to fail to understand the answers. Undefined Behaviour means *anything can happen*. It makes no sense to talk about "what is the use of pass by value" etc.  Your program has a bug, end of story. Fix the bug and then the problem goes away.  Your program does not follow the rules of C++ so the expectations of a C++ program do not apply to it.

Comment: @Distraction you pass by value complex class type `std::string`. Would you modify the string properly, the original string would be intact. But you somehow assumed something about implementation, imagining "pass by value means there are two strings in memory". You shouldn't make any assumptions about implementation. The API is defined as is, and as long as you use it correctly, the "pass by value" works well for `std::string` too, so there's no problem. Your problem is solved by `a[2] = 'x';`, removing useless `buff`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void test(std::string a)
{
    // modification trough valid std::string API
    a[2] = 'x';
    const char *buff  = a.c_str(); // only const char* is available from API
    std::cout << "In function: "  << a << " | Trough pointer: " << buff;

    // extraction to writeable char[] buffer
    char writeableBuff[100];

    // unsafe, possible attack trough buffer overflow, don't use in real code
    strcpy(writeableBuff, a.c_str());

    writeableBuff[3] = 'y';
    std::cout << "\n" << "In writeable buffer: "  << writeableBuff;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "Hello World";
    std::cout  << "Before : "<< s << "\n" ;
    test(s);
    std::cout << "\n" << "After : " << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Before : Hello World
In function: Hexlo World | Trough pointer: Hexlo World
In writeable buffer: Hexyo World
After : Hello World
```